# How to automatically trigger missed Tasker profiles after power outage?

Tags: tasker

I have a phone running Android 8(Non rooted) and tasker with some tasks scheduled to run at specific time.

How can I make tasks which hadn't run because the phone was out of power, to run when power comes back.

What I`m searching for basically, is Anacron for Tasker